# add raw sql where clause to django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is it possible to add an additional raw sql clause to a django queryset?
Preferably with the `RawSQL` clause to a normal queryset.
It should be a normal queryset and not a rawqueryset because I want to use it in the django admin.

In my particular case I want to add an additonal `exists` where clause:

```
and exists (
   select 1
   from ...
)
```

In my concrete case I have two models `Customer` and `Subscription`. The `Subscription` has a `start` and optional `end` date field.

I want to have a queryset with all customers which have a current subscription today. Like this SQL query:

```
select *
from customers_customer c
where exists (
  select 1
  from subscriptions_subscription sc
  where sc.customer_id = c.id
  and sc.start < current_date
  and (sc.end is null or sc.end > current_date)
)
```

I was not able to make a queryset out of this.
The best thing I arrived, was something like:

```
    cs = Customer.objects.annotate(num_subscriptions=RawSQL(
        '''
        select count(sc.id)
        from subscriptions_customersubscription sc
        where sc.customer_id = customers_customer.id
        and sc.start < current_date
        and (sc.end is null or sc.end > current_date)
        ''', []
    ))
```

But this query does not perform as well as the SQL-query with the `where exists`.

Comment: Can you post your models? You are trying to manually join tables, was there a problem with doing it naturally like `Customer.objects.filter(subscriptions__start__lt=current_date)` etc?

Comment: OK the natural join works and does exactly what I want to have... I just didn't think of it...

Answer (score 2):

Not answering your question, but you can query customers like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Customer.objects.filter(
    Q(subscription__start__lt=current_date),
    Q(subscription__end=None) | Q (subscription__end__gt=current_date)
).distinct()
```

Comment: Well I did not think of the easy solution. Although this does not answer the question, it solves my problem so :upvote

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the original question, one can use the `QuerySet.extra()` method to add raw SQL as explained [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra)